# Add a button at the WordPress Backend Pages menu

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi everybody I am wondering how I can make a button to edit the page content with the WordPress backend, like Visual Composer does. I could not find any code to insert a simple button to edit a page with my own plugin.

[Picture of the WordPress Backend with Visual Composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm5i6.png)

In this picture you can see the two blue buttons, I can not create.

Comment: Michael - in order to help you, we need: 1) the code you've tried so far, and 2) what it is you want the button to do.  We can show you how to add **a button**, but is that enough? Is that all you are asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you are familiar with [WordPress Hooks](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/definitive-guide-wordpress-hooks/), but hooks are the magic of how things like this are done in WordPress.

The particular hook you are looking for is this:

```
do_action( 'edit_form_after_title', $post );
```

The hook above is **called** in the WordPress "edit" interface (in file `wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php`.

If you want to do something at that location, then you need to access that hook by [adding an action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action):

So, your code (in your plugin) would look something like this:

```
// Tells WP to do something at the do_action mentioned above
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'my_function_name');

// This is the function specified in the "add_action" above
function my_function_name( $post ) {
   // Do stuff here.
   echo '<a href="#" class="button-primary">My Button</a>';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I wanted and it is going to help me. I am about to create a page builder plugin like Visual Composer.